# Common setup for parallel Jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins build that syncs SVN to a given changelist and then builds code for various different configurations in parallel. I have a prebuild step that needs to be run once per agent regardless of how many builds that agent will build. My current declarative pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages
{   
    stage('parallel')
    {
        failFast true

        parallel
        {
            stage('Release')
            {
                agent {
                    label {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                }                   
                steps
                {
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM',
                    additionalCredentials: [],
                    excludedCommitMessages: '',
                    excludedRegions: '',
                    excludedRevprop: '',
                    excludedUsers: '',
                    filterChangelog: false,
                    ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                    includedRegions: '',
                    locations: [[credentialsId: 'SVN',
                        depthOption: 'infinity',
                        ignoreExternalsOption: false,
                        local: '.',
                        remote: 'https://my-repo']],
                    workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])

                    bat 'Prebuild.bat'
                    bat 'msbuild Game/Code/Application.sln "Release|x64"'
                }
            }
            stage('Debug Optimized')
            {
                agent {
                    label {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                }
                steps
                {
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM',
                    additionalCredentials: [],
                    excludedCommitMessages: '',
                    excludedRegions: '',
                    excludedRevprop: '',
                    excludedUsers: '',
                    filterChangelog: false,
                    ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
                    includedRegions: '',
                    locations: [[credentialsId: 'SVN',
                        depthOption: 'infinity',
                        ignoreExternalsOption: false,
                        local: '.',
                        remote: 'https://my-repo']],
                    workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])

                    bat 'Prebuild.bat'
                    bat 'msbuild Game/Code/Application.sln "Debug Optimized|x64"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

While this works a) it's unmaintainable (I have about 20 configs to build in reality, and I don't want to maintain 20 copies of my scm settings), b) it's running the checkout/prebuild once per stage rather than once per agent. I notice there is a default checkout for agents, but as far as I can tell this doesn't work with SVN.

Is there a better way of doing parallel stages than this?

Comment: You could do the checkout in one stage and stash the sources. Then unstash them as the first step in the parallel stages. I've done that using a scripted pipeline though.

Comment: My branch is too big (10s of GB) for that to be viable, unfortunately

Comment: Not sure about the declarative pipeline, but at least with the scripted pipeline you can checkout and then do further stuff in a single stage (or in subsequent stages). You can call "parallel" over a set of "nodes" that each execute a sequence of stages. Concerning the maintenance of the scm-settings: perhaps you can move those to a shared library. See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

did you heard about Jenkins Multijob plugin?
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Could it fit your need?

You have also the possibility to build downstream job, when one of your job is finished.

Comment: That would mean abandoning pipeline though, right? I really like the philosophy behind pipeline files.